# Visual Basic: DataTable.Search filter args

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to search through an SQL table of records to find and extract those records whose fields match my criteria.

The field name is ID and it is a 13 digit code, stored as Integer in the SQL itself. I need to search each record by the first six digits of the ID field (not primary key field).

Below is the code:

```vb
Dim results As DataSet.DataRow() = DataSet.DataTable.Select("LEFT(ID,6) = 123456")
```

Here is the error message:

```
The expression contains undefined function call LEFT().
```

I suspect the problem is with the LEFT function in the SQL filter - because if I run .Select on, say, "ID = some-ID-value", the corresponding record is returned properly.

Perhaps SQL functions are not recognized when the .Select() is used? Or maybe I should use CAST?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: [DataTable Select Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) syntax and supported words

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to create a DataView with your existing DataTable; apply filter and get filtered rows into another data table.  This is safe code.

```
 DataView dataView = new DataView(DataSet.DataTable);
 dataView.RowFilter = "ID LIKE '123456%'";
 var filtredData = dataView.ToTable();
```

Comment: didn't realize you are in vb.net; hope you can convert to equivalent code

Comment: Better to explain what you are doing here.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Here is the solution in VB:

        Dim results As DataSet.DataRow() = DataSet.DataTable.Select("ID LIKE '%123456%'")

Comment: adding percentage in the beginning and the end would check for digits anywhere in the ID but not just at beginning...